# How i set the custom email template in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates

In magento 2.0 use this `{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}`

how i use this in magento 2.1

Comment: AFAIK, we can use the same pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is same as `Magento 2.o`, you can also confirm from any Magento module, like example I checked Magento `sales` module and I found the, `order_new_guest.html` from the `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\email\order_new_guest.html`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.getBillingAddress().getName()":"Guest Customer Name",
"var order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2)":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order."}}
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of create **etc/email_template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template id="customemail_email_template" label="Email Form" file="customemail.html" type="html" module="Codextblog_Customemail" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

then as module define in xml file create html file in that module

**view/frontend/email/customemail.html**

```
<!--@subject Sending email from my custom module @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table style="width:100%;">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Booking Your Free Slot</h1>
     <tr class="email-intro">
         <td>
         <b>Email:</b> {{var email}}
         </td>
         <td>
         <b>Name:</b> {{var name}}
         </td>
          <td>
         <b>Mobile:</b> {{var mobile}}
         </td>
          <td>
         <b>Language:</b> {{var language}}
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```